# Sharing an applet across Tomcat applications

Tags: java, tomcat, applet

I have a Java applet that is used by a couple of web application running in Tomcat.

What is the best way to share the applet? If I put the applet in `catalina_home/shared/lib`, how do I reference it when setting the codebase in the JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an applet (not a servlet) you'll need to put the jar somewhere on a publically available webserver, so that it can be served to the client. In tomcat's global lib directory, you're making it available on the classpath of the server - an applet is never executed on the server, but only on the client (browser).

Whatever location/URL you choose for the applet's jar, you'll need to use in the applet's HTML element `<applet .../>` (is this still in use? I didn't use applets for > 10 years - there might be better ways to embed an applet nowadays). As this is only a question of naming the correct URL for the applet's jar file in your HTML, there's no problem sharing one jar between several web applications

Comment: *you'll need to use in the applet's HTML element `<applet .../>` (is this still in use?"*  The best way today is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) to (check for a suitable minimum JRE before) writing the element understood by that browser.